# How can I pass a C++ String through reference?

Tags: c++

I am writing a huffcode program, and I'm going through every branch of the tree to to find the code for each alphabet. How can I pass the string to insert it? Also, Im getting errors from the way I declared my string vector, but Ive used vectors all over my code. Is there something I am doing wrong?

```
void treeTraverser(Node* root, char string, vector<char> const &alpha,
vector<string> const &huffcode){
 if(root->left!=NULL){
     string=string+'0';
     treeTraverser(root->left, string, alpha, huffcode);
  }
 if(root->right!=NULL){
    string=string+'1';
    treeTraverser(root->right, string, alpha, huffcode);
  }
   alpha.push_back(root->key);
   huffcode.push_back(string);
}
```

Comment: When you get errors, and you want help with them, you should tell us what they are?

Answer (score 0):

Change `char` to `string&` in your `string` parameter (and consider renaming it, too).

Also, get rid of the `const` on the `huffcode` parameter. You can't `push_back()` into a `const vector` object.

```cpp
void treeTraverser(Node* root, string &str, vector<char> const &alpha, vector<string> &huffcode)
{
  if (root->left){
    str += '0';
    treeTraverser(root->left, str, alpha, huffcode);
  }
  if (root->right){
    str += '1';
    treeTraverser(root->right, str, alpha, huffcode);
  }
  alpha.push_back(root->key);
  huffcode.push_back(str);
}
```